# How to get Postgres (.sql) file generated by Django>

Tags: django, postgresql

I am developing a website with Django and I connected Django to Postgres. Now I want to view the Postgres SQL generated by Django but I don't seem to find it. I know an SQL developer who wants to have a look at how the database is and I replied that I can absolutely get him the SQL file and I don't know how to, I've searched a lot and ended up asking here.

Comment: You could try using pg_dump: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/backup-dump.html

Comment: @Fifon Much Thanks, That worked!